# Draw Tikz Tree where level distance between multi-line nodes is constant

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I am drawing a tree with tikz, namely, using tikz-qtree-compat for simpler syntax.
On the tree there can be nodes of different height but then branches become messy.
I want to add an instruction where distance between the south point of a mother nodes and the north point of a child node is constant.

MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/2453721thvhsh#/6394537/

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}  % draw trees with simple syntax

\begin{document}

wanted but obtained non-general way:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-20pt, grow=down]
\tikzset{level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 30pt}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=38pt}}  
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=60pt}}  
\tikzset{level 4/.style={level distance=60pt}}  
\Tree
[.\node{A\\A};
 [.\node{B\\B\\B\\B};
  [.\node{C};
   [.\node{E\\E\\E};]
  ]
  [.\node{D\\D\\D};
   [.\node at(0,-25pt){F\\F};
    [.\node{G};]
   ]
  ] 
 ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

without any modification looks like:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-20pt, grow=down]
\tikzset{level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 30pt}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
%\tikzet{some single instruction that fix all trees in this way}
\Tree
[.\node{A\\A};
 [.\node{B\\B\\B\\B};
  [.\node{C};
   [.\node{E\\E\\E};]
  ]
  [.\node{D\\D\\D};
   [.\node{F\\F};
    [.\node{G};]
   ]
  ] 
 ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `growth parent anchor=north`? See "Custom Growth Functions" in the PGF manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) you can get what you want with a not too complex syntax:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}  
[A\\A, for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center, s sep=5mm}
 [B\\B\\B\\B
  [C [E\\E\\E]]
  [D\\D\\D [F\\F [G]]]
 ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on [Ignasi's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235267/) which tries to illustrate the process of converting the tree to `forest` and how to align the tree with the surrounding text in an equivalent way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

  a forest solution:
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      align=center,% will apply to every node in the tree, enables multiline nodes with centred alignment of text
      parent anchor=south,% required to emulate the behaviour of the target tree
      child anchor=north,% required to emulate the behaviour of the target tree
      s sep=30pt,% equivalent of setting sibling distance, I think
      l sep=10pt,% similar to setting level distance, I think
    }
    [A\\A, anchor=center, baseline% you need to specify the baseline differently to align the tree in a particular way with the surrounding text
     [B\\B\\B\\B
      [C
       [E\\E\\E]
      ]
      [D\\D\\D
       [F\\F
        [G]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: another forest tree]